# issue in emailable testng report - selenium

Tags: testng

I am trying to attach a screen print inside testng report. this is working fine in index.html report but in emailable report it just html markup,when I checked the html file it logged as html escaps, any help on this

```
Reporter.log("<a title= \"title\" href=\"\">" +"<img width=\"218\" height=\"300\"  src=\""+imageValue+"\" /></a>");
```

TestNG version is 6.9[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`Reporter.setEscapeHtml(true)`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Reporter.html#setEscapeHtml-boolean-) before the log?

Comment: no I didn't do that, even I tried Reporter.setEscapeHtml(false); before log but not worked :( in email-able report

Comment: Ok. You should open a new issue on the project, or better, find the problem and pull request the fix.